# SQL How to select data (countries) that only has code with 3 characters?

Tags: sql

I have to extract all the list of countries. however in the datatable under country column (2nd column), it includes continent as well, which is not what i want.

I realised those with the first column (iso_code) with only 3 characters are data with countries, while those with more than 3 characters are continents/non country. How do i go about extracting this?

[image]

this is my current code when extracting everything (including continent that are under country column) :

```
select count(distinct country) as "Number of Countries"
FROM owid_energy_data
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Difficult to tell because you did not name the `DBMS` you are using, like IBM `db2` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking to extract all the distinct names of countries from a column where you have first three letters always as a country name then use this:

```
select distinct left(country,3) as country from owid_energy_data
```

selecting the countries, where the iso_code (first column) has only three letters:

```
select distinct country as countries from owid_energy_data where length(iso_code) = 3
```

if you want the count then simply add count to one of the above:

```
select  count(distinct country) as total_countries from owid_energy_data
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much. But actually what i want is the country with code that contains 3 letter (first column). you may refer to the photo in the question. Thank you

Comment: @Samantha use the second query i.e `select distinct country as countries from owid_energy_data where length(iso_code) = 3` , it is selecting all the unique / distinct countries (second column) for all the cases where you have 3 words in the iso_code i.e (first column)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select count(distinct country) as "Number of Countries" 
FROM owid_energy_data    
where len(iso_code) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OED.COUNTRY AS [NUMBER OF COUNTRIES]
FROM OWID_ENERGY_DATA OED
WHERE LEN(OED.COUNTRY) < 3
```

Try that!

Answer (score 0):

Display only the 3-character country code (Code column) and name (in English and in the local language) of the countries that are located in Europe.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't understand. Why is the "local language" relevant and also why are only European countries relevant? Are you actually asking another question? Have you taken the [tour]?