# NOSQL MONGODB How to select data (countries) that only has code with 3 characters?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

[SQL How to select data (countries) that only has code with 3 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261797/sql-how-to-select-data-countries-that-only-has-code-with-3-characters)

My issue is the same as above link, but just that i have to do it in nosql.

I have to extract all the list of countries. however in the datatable under country column (2nd column), it includes continent as well, which is not what i want.

I realised those with the first column (iso_code) with only 3 characters are data with countries, while those with more than 3 characters are continents/non country. How do i go about extracting this?

my code in extracting everything:

```
db.owid_energy_data.distinct("country")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$strLenCP` to compute the length of `iso_code`. `$match` with 3 to get the documents needed. `$group` to find distinct countries.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          3,
          {
            "$strLenCP": "$iso_code"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mIGFfzbDo7j)